# Accumulating Multiple Results In a Dictionary

Tags: python, list, accumulator

The question as below:
**Create a dictionary called char_d from the string stri, so that the key is a character and the value is how many times it occurs.**

**this is the code i tried:**

```
stri = "what can I do"
char_d={}
lst=stri.split()
for wrd in lst:
    for c in wrd:
        if c not in char_d:
        char_d[c]=0
    char_d[c]+=1
```

the output i get is:

[('h', 1), ('o', 1), ('c', 1), ('t', 1), ('n', 1), ('d', 1), ('I', 1), ('a', 2), ('w', 1)]

the expected value should include:
(' ',3)

i think the value should be including the space but how we do it?

Comment: Split discards spaces. Don’t split. Iterate on the string directly.

Comment: If you can use builtin libraries, you might find [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) very useful for this scenario.

Comment: The indentation of your code is broken for the last two lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you proposed works. You can use `get` method of dictionary to be more pythonic.

```
stri = "what can I do"
char_d={}
#lst=stri.split()
#for wrd in stri:
for c in stri:
   char_d[c] = char_d.get(c, 0) + 1
```

`get(c, 0)` will return 0 if c does not exist in the dict.

You can also use Counter from collections.

```
char_d = Counter(stri)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stri = "what can I do"
char_d={}
#lst=stri.split()
#for wrd in stri:
for c in stri:
   if c not in char_d:
      char_d[c]=0
   char_d[c]+=1
```

I think i found a solution but will appreciate it if there is any further explaination.

Comment: explanation for which part exactly?

Comment: The explanation is obvious by actually looking at what the code does. By making a list of words, iterating over the words and then iterating over the letters in each word, you don't include the spaces - because the words don't have spaces in them. You fix the problem by directly iterating over the entire string, because the string does have the spaces in it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your dictionary does not contain the whitespace character is because you used the .split() method.

```
lst=stri.split()
```

Because there are no parameters between the parentheses, the split() method used the default (the whitespace character) to divide the string into an ordered sequence and returns that as a list object.

```
['what', 'can', 'I', 'do']
```

You can pass any string (or object that evaluates to string) to the method, a la:

`lst=stri.split('a')`

This will split `stri` by the character 'a' instead, yielding:

```
['wh', 't c', 'n I do']
```

In every case, the demarcating character(s) that the split method uses is lost in the process.